# How to find perspectivity of the ranges on a line

Tags: projective-geometry

[image]

Question: Complete the perspectivity of the ranges on the lines $AB$ and $DF$ with centre $H$: 
$ABF$ $\barwedge$ ?
 I got $F$ as my first point but is lost after that. Need help. Also I was told to label my own lines on this picture

Answer (score 1):

The perspectivity $AB\to DF$ of center $H$ sends $A\mapsto I$, where $I=AH\cap DF$, $B\mapsto E$ and $F\mapsto F$, thus you have to complete $ABF\barwedge IEF$.

Comment: I see now but after that I have to use $IEF$ through the center point?

Comment: Also how did you do that symbol? I could not input it correctly

Comment: The symbol $ABF \barwedge IEF$ (\barwedge) means that perspectivity of center $H$ sends the group $ABF$ into the group $IEF$.

Comment: One more thing, why it couldn't be $IEG$? $G$ falls on the same line as point F

Comment: No, becuase the point $G$ doesn't belongs to the line $DF$.